# Maximo anywhere mobile app support for android versions

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Could anyone please share the supporting versions of android devices in maximo anywhere mobile apps deployment

Comment: Does it supports android lollipop versions

Answer (score 0):

We support Android 4 and Android 5 with 7521 currently.  We're certifying Android 6 soon.